Enable Cors in Swagger .NET
I have this program.cs file for my .NET web api application:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
});

app.Run();

If I run the application and call the api it will redirect. However, When I call the api from swagger, it will return CORS error. As it's shown I have enabled CORS but it doesn't work.
I have tried moving the api into a Controller and using EnableCors attribute but it didn't work.

What error are you getting? Add it to your question (as text, not as a picture).

Try this:
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("url to your site")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
});

Replace "url to your site" with the url of the site you want to allow to call your api.
